# UK - Accidentally applied for passport renewal instead of new

Tags: uk, passports, applications, fees-and-charges

I applied for a British renewal passport online by mistake instead of new British passport. I have already paid online for it and received my declaration pack. What can I do to rectify this error? Is applying for a new passport and ignoring this is sufficient? Is refund option available?

Comment: You may not be able to do anything. According to https://www.gov.uk/passport-fees you cannot get a refund if you cancel your application.

Comment: Are you certain that you have made a mistake?  So-called passport renewal is generally misnamed, since it usually concerns getting a new passport within a certain amount of time after the previous one has expired.  But it's not actually possible to literally renew an expiring or expired passport; the first document is always replaced with a new one that has a new passport number.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.